# Reduce coil whine in LED driver

Tags: inductor, led-driver

I have designed a PCB to control RGB LEDs at various intensities using the PWM input to an ALW8808WT-7 driver from an STM32RCT MCU.

The 33 uH inductors in my prototype board let off an awful whine while the LEDs are running.

Is there a way to design around this for my next board? I have attached a picture of the schematic for reference.

[image]

Comment: What is the switching frequency? Is your circuit pulse skipping?

Comment: The audible frequency <20kHz has to come from somewhere. What is your control signal? Is the 24V reasonably clean (small ripple)?

Comment: @TomFlynn:  What is the frequency of the PWM signal?

Comment: Note that ceramic capacitors can also emit sound. You could try touching one with a wood or plastic stick and listen for any change in the noise.

Comment: You are probably hearing the third harmonic. Can you change the PWM frequency and move that harmonic out of audio range. Possibly a different style inductor or slightly different value may work.

Comment: World's most elusive IC? The only thing that comes up when searching for an ALW8808WT-7 datasheet is this question.

Comment: @pipe Look for AL8808 as in the schematic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The conversion frequency of all these chips is way above the audible range; so on the face of it you should not get any audio whine. Well there are ways that you still can. Check the coil for saturation, remember that the chip peak current is much more than the LED current, a bigger coil should be better. Also put a scope on the switching node. You may not see a nice even square wave at the switching frequency. Instability often occurs at audio frequency. Also check on the scope for subharmonic oscillations which plauge these basic chips.

Comment: @TomF Which part of this answer solved the problem for you?

Comment: I tried a larger inductor and that seemed to do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

The audible whine is caused by small movements of the inductor windings; you may be able to find potted inductors or you can dip them in resinous laquer to seal the windings.  Also check your PWM frequency; this may be the source of the whine or it may be interacting with the switcher frequency somehow.

Comment: Or, if you don't have resinous lacquer (it's not exactly a common household item, after all), a bit of hot glue works well too.

Comment: Nor are inductors… whatever you use, it needs to penetrate well into the windings.  Ideally you’d put the dipped inductors into a (household) vacuum chamber to remove air bubbles, but anything is better than nothing.  Sourcing encapsulated inductors might be easiest.